# Как прикрепить текст к фото отправленным с помощью file_id на Aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Нужно чтобы бот присылал фото через file_id, но к нему был прикреплен определенный текст. В документации покопался но ни к чему не пришел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохо вы копались в документации. В методе [send_photo](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/api/methods/send_photo.html) есть caption, в котором вы указываете текст подписи

Будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user.id, photo=file_id, caption="Какой-то текст под фото")
```